# Magento Session for specific customer

Tags: php, magento, session, e-commerce, magento-1.8

Working on `Localhost`.
I want to store a session value for each specific customer.

When i store my value in `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyVal('something')` the same value appears in all customers. I was scared when i saw this... It was like customer session hijacking. I want the session to be private foreach customer.

When i used `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setMyVal('something')`, i got this "something" using a customer account and then logged out and logged in with different customer and i saw the same "something" again...

For example if i want to store "logged in datetime" it should be different foreach customer of course. Or i have not understand how PHP sessions work.

Comment: Sessions are tied to browser sessions. It is possible that even when logging out the session isn't fully destroyed but could still be accessible from that computer with that browser session, but it should be accessible to anyone else. What you should try is opening the same page on different browsers or other one in incognito mode and see if the values are still same. Session id is stored in a cookie

Comment: Indeed when I login from 2 different browsers with 2 different customers OR if i delete that "frontend" cookie then it all works as expected. Please post your answer below so i check it as correct answer.

Comment: So, if i login to a Magento store using a public computer and make an order then if someone else log in from the same computer to to the same store using a different customer account it is possible to see my personal session data...? Maybe this is one of the reasons why Bank applications suggest not to login from a public computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are tied to browser sessions. It is possible that even when logging out the session isn't fully destroyed but could still be accessible from that computer with that browser session, but it should be accessible to anyone else. What you should try is opening the same page on different browsers or other one in incognito mode and see if the values are still same. Session id is stored in a cookie

If you want to destroy the session on login find magento logout handler and add session_destroy(); there or unset your custom session variables there.

Also sessions are the reason why you should clean cookies and other info when leaving public computer. Also logout handler should remove all user details from session. Session data is stored on the server and visitors can't see what is stored there if you don't output your session data to user.

Comment: Yes, but in my case i need to output/show a specific session value to the customer. That's why i wanted to ensure that it will remail private.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help you, with little bit tricky

```
$sess_var = array (
     "custId" => Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId(),
     "value"=> "your value here"
);

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setMyVal($sess_var)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use customers ID while storing the session for customer (as mentioned by Ansyori) but be sure to destroy it on logout.